# warning message regarding block templates after update wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated my `wp-site` to the latest version yesterday and now get the following warning message:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
> callback, function 'wp_enable_block_templates' not found or invalid
> function name in
> /www/doc/www.zanggroepvocalis.nl/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
> line 303

Looking into `class-wp-hook.php` line 303 says:

```
303             $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

Any suggestions what I can do to solve this?

Comment: More often than not this is caused by a plugin (potentially out of date). Check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433518/warning-call-user-func-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback), it's a good starting point for debugging issues like these.

Comment: I manually updated wp and now it is working again, so problem solved.